# why are there '#' in form attributes

Tags: drupal

When using forms. why put '#' for the keys? Any special reason?

```
$form['a'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Score if not chosen'),
      );
```

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33227/what-are-properties

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, it's a convention to add a hash tag (#) to the beginning of variable names that correspond to a setting, rather than an element. This is done to avoid namespace collisions.